# SQL insert into error: parameters are of unsupported type

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite

I'm writing my first script with `sqlite` and have not been able to insert a fictional observation into the data with `insert into`. Here is my attempt:

```py
from pandas import read_csv, read_sql_query
from pathlib import Path
from sqlite3 import connect

Path('database.db').touch()
conn = connect('database.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(
    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS spiders ('
        'record_id INT, month INT, day INT, year INT,'
        'plot_id INT, species_id CHAR(2), sex CHAR(1), hindfoot_length FLOAT,'
        ' weight FLOAT'
        ')'
        )
data = read_csv('surveys.csv')
data = data.dropna()
data.to_sql('spiders', conn, if_exists='append', index=False)

query_1 = read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM spiders', conn)
print('The first five rows of the data:\n')
print(query_1.head())

c.execute(
    'INSERT INTO spiders ('
        'record_id, month, day, year, plot_id, species_id, sex, '
        'hindfoot_length, weight'
        ') VALUES (0, 7, 31, 2023, 2, "DM", "F", 99.0, 60.0)', conn
    )
```

Here is the output with traceback:

```
The first five rows of the data:

   record_id  month  day  year  plot_id species_id sex  hindfoot_length  weight
0         63      8   19  1977        3         DM   M             35.0    40.0
1         64      8   19  1977        7         DM   M             37.0    48.0
2         65      8   19  1977        4         DM   F             34.0    29.0
3         66      8   19  1977        4         DM   F             35.0    46.0
4         67      8   19  1977        7         DM   M             35.0    36.0

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~/mambaforge/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File ~/Desktop/data/sql_demo.py:38
    c.execute(

ProgrammingError: parameters are of unsupported type
```

What is wrong in my script?

Comment: The problem is the `conn` parameter.  You do not need to pass the connection to `execute`.  It gets the connection from the cursor.  That parameter is supposed to contain the list of items to be substituted into the query, and `execute` did not recognize the type of that parameter.

Comment: The second argument to `c.execute()` is a list of values to fill in placeholders in the SQL. If there are no placeholders, just leave out the argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `conn` parameter.  You do not need to pass the connection to `execute`.  It gets the connection from the cursor.  That parameter is supposed to contain the list of items to be substituted into the query, and `execute` did not recognize the type of that parameter.

If you're not doing substitution, do:

```
c.execute(
    'INSERT INTO spiders ('
        'record_id, month, day, year, plot_id, species_id, sex, '
        'hindfoot_length, weight'
        ') VALUES (0, 7, 31, 2023, 2, "DM", "F", 99.0, 60.0)'
    )
```

but it would be better practice to do:

```
c.execute(
    'INSERT INTO spiders ('
        'record_id, month, day, year, plot_id, species_id, sex, '
        'hindfoot_length, weight'
        ') VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);',
        (0, 7, 31, 2023, 2, "DM", "F", 99.0, 60.0)
    )
```